# Prove That if |a|=m and |b|=n and ⟨a⟩∩⟨b⟩={e} then, gcd(m, n)=1

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

$G$ is a group and $a,b,\in G$.

To summarize the question, if the cyclic group generated by $a$ and $b$ only has the identity element in common, then the orders of $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

I'm not sure how to proceed. What should I start with?

Comment: Please read this before posting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to better format your questions in future. I fixed the formatting of this first question, but you should not expect others to do this for you!

Comment: Is $G$ supposed to be cyclic? Because this fails even for the Klein-4 group $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: @Arthur G is not supposed to be cyclic

Comment: If G was cyclic, would that change anything?

Comment: If $G$ were cyclic then there is a unique subgroup of $G$ of order gcd$(m,n)$ which is contained in $\langle a\rangle$ and in $\langle b\rangle$.

Comment: As an aside, when you don't know where to start, try a few examples. In this case if you take any group with two elements $a,b$ of order $2$ you would find a counterexample.

Answer (score 9):

This is false. Take, for instance, the group $S_3$, and then take $a=(1\ \ 2)$, and $b=(1\ \ 3)$. Then $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle=\{e\}$. However, but both $a$ and $b$ have order $2$.